# Save/Load Snake position in the console game Snake

Tags: c#, console-application

I'm trying to learn how to save and load in console games.At the moment I'm trying to load the snake position from a file. The snake is a List with X and Y coordinates of each element.

The problem I have is that the snake doesn't load from the registered position.I suppose that the problem is with the reading.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;

namespace MySnake
{

    struct Position
    {
        public int Row;

        public int Col;

        public Position(int row, int col)
        {
            this.Row = row;
            this.Col = col;
        }

    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            byte right = 0;
            byte left = 1;
            byte down = 2;
            byte up = 3;

            Position[] directions =
            {
                new Position(0,1), // right
                new Position(0,-1), // left
                new Position(1,0), // down
                new Position(-1,0), // up

            };

            int direction = 0;

            Console.SetBufferSize(100, 100);
            Console.SetWindowSize(Console.BufferWidth, Console.BufferHeight);

            List<Position> snake = new List<Position>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                snake.Add(new Position(0, 1));
            }

            Draw(snake,"*");

            while (true)
            {

                if (Console.KeyAvailable)
                {

                    ConsoleKeyInfo userImput = Console.ReadKey();

                    if (userImput.Key == ConsoleKey.LeftArrow)
                    {
                        if (direction != right)
                        {
                            direction = 1;
                        }

                    }
                    if (userImput.Key == ConsoleKey.RightArrow)
                    {
                        if (direction != left)
                        {
                            direction = 0;
                        }

                    }
                    if (userImput.Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow)
                    {
                        if (direction != down)
                        {
                            direction = 3;
                        }

                    }
                    if (userImput.Key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow)
                    {
                        if (direction != up)
                        {
                            direction = 2;
                        }

                    }
                    if (userImput.Key == ConsoleKey.S)
                    {
                        SaveGame(snake);
                    }
                    if (userImput.Key == ConsoleKey.L)
                    {
                        LoadGame(snake);
                    }

                }

                Position snakeHead = snake.Last();
                Position snakeNewHead = new Position(snakeHead.Row + directions[direction].Row, snakeHead.Col + directions[direction].Col);


                snake.Add(snakeNewHead);
            Draw(snakeNewHead,"*");

                Console.SetCursorPosition(snake[0].Col, snake[0].Row);
                Console.Write(' ');
                snake.RemoveAt(0); // take off at the back!!


                Thread.Sleep(100);//100ms
            }
        }      
        private static void Draw(List<Position> smth,string str)
        {
            foreach (var position in smth)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(position.Col, position.Row);
                Console.Write(str);
            }
        }
        private static void Draw(Position smth,string str)
        {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(smth.Col, smth.Row);
                Console.Write(str);
        }
        private static void LoadGame(List<Position> snake)
        {
            int snakeCount = snake.Count;
            snake.Clear();

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("savegame.jcn");
            using (reader)
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < snakeCount; i++)
                {
                    string[] text = reader.ReadLine().Split(' ');
                    snake.Add(new Position(int.Parse(text[0]), int.Parse(text[1])));
                }

            }
        }
        private static void SaveGame(List<Position>snake)
        {
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("savegame.jcn");
            using (writer)
            {
                foreach (var element in snake)
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(element.Col + " " + element.Row);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Hi Julian.  Please read how to create a [mcve] and then [edit] your question to include something that we can run so that we can see the same problem.  This is also an excellent time to learn to use your debugger, which will let you step through your program one line at a time and see exactly what is going on.

Comment: Also you might have a look at the static `File` methods (`using System.IO`) that you can use to read and write text files (they're easier than using StreamReader/Writers, since they wrap most of that functionality into methods like `File.ReadAllLines` or `File.WriteAllLines`).

Comment: Thanks for the advises. I'm new here so I didn't know how it works. I took off all unnecessary staff from the code.

Answer (score 0):

Give this version a go:

```
struct Position
{
    public int Row;
    public int Col;
    public Position(int row, int col)
    {
        this.Row = row;
        this.Col = col;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        byte right = 0;
        byte left = 1;
        byte down = 2;
        byte up = 3;

        Position[] directions =
        {
            new Position(0, 1), // right
            new Position(0, -1), // left
            new Position(1, 0), // down
            new Position(-1, 0), // up
        };

        int direction = right;

        Console.SetBufferSize(100, 100);
        Console.SetWindowSize(Console.BufferWidth, Console.BufferHeight);

        List<Position> snake = new List<Position>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            snake.Add(new Position(0, 1));
        }

        Draw(snake, "*");

        while (true)
        {

            if (Console.KeyAvailable)
            {
                ConsoleKeyInfo userImput = Console.ReadKey();

                var moves = new []
                {
                    new { key = ConsoleKey.LeftArrow, no = right, yes = left },
                    new { key = ConsoleKey.RightArrow, no = left, yes = right },
                    new { key = ConsoleKey.UpArrow, no = down, yes = up },
                    new { key = ConsoleKey.DownArrow, no = up, yes = down },
                }

                moves
                    .Where(x => x.key == userImput.Key)
                    .Where(x => x.no != direction)
                    .ToList()
                    .ForEach(x => direction = x.yes);

                if (userImput.Key == ConsoleKey.S)
                {
                    SaveGame(snake);
                }

                if (userImput.Key == ConsoleKey.L)
                {
                    LoadGame(snake);
                }
            }

            Position snakeHead = snake.Last();
            Position snakeNewHead = new Position(snakeHead.Row + directions[direction].Row, snakeHead.Col + directions[direction].Col);

            snake.Add(snakeNewHead);
            Draw(snakeNewHead, "*");

            Console.SetCursorPosition(snake[0].Col, snake[0].Row);
            Console.Write(' ');
            snake.RemoveAt(0); // take off at the back!!

            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100.0));
        }
    }

    private static void Draw(List<Position> smth, string str)
    {
        foreach (var position in smth)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(position.Col, position.Row);
            Console.Write(str);
        }
    }

    private static void Draw(Position smth, string str)
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(smth.Col, smth.Row);
        Console.Write(str);
    }

    private static void LoadGame(List<Position> snake)
    {
        snake.Clear();
        snake.AddRange(
            File
                .ReadAllLines("savegame.jcn")
                .Select(x => x.Split(' '))
                .Select(x => new Position(int.Parse(x[0]), int.Parse(x[1]))));
    }

    private static void SaveGame(List<Position> snake)
    {
        File.WriteAllLines("savegame.jcn", snake.Select(x => $"{x.Col} {x.Row}"));
    }
}
```

The key thing here is the use of `File.ReadAllLines` and `File.WriteAllLines`.

Comment: Thank you.It works very well like this but I'm doing it with StreamWriter/Reader because I have a lot of values to save and read, not just the snake position. Like direction, food position,score, level, lives,screen size etc... And like this i can save it on just one file. With File I couldn't find a way to do it line by line without rewrite the line of the previous entry. Here the code is not complete. I just took off  the part of the code that wasn't relevant to the problem.

Comment: @JulianDocev - All you need to do to save multiple different items is to create several `List<string>` and then just do `File.WriteAllLines(directions.Concat(foods).Concat(score))` etc. Then when you load you just need some way to determine what each line is so that you can filter the list before repopulating your data. Working with streams is generally difficult and outdated unless you are dealing with vast quantities of data - streams don't hold on to large amounts of memory, but a `List<string>` does. But I'm talking many many megabytes before it is an issue.

Comment: @Eigmativity-Thank you very much for your advice. It is very helpful.